# Are there any native cursive fonts on ios 7+

Tags: iphone, ios, font

I have searched iosfonts.com and only see Zaphino as a native cursive font.

Are there any others?

Or do I need to install them into my app or make my own images?

Comment: You said you searched iosfonts.com and you saw only 1 native cursive font. What could that mean? It means there is only 1 native cursive font. Fire up Xcode and check it out. If there were any other, I think it would have been on the website. So for new cursive fonts, you'll obviously need to install new fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Snell Roundhand, source: http://iosfonts.com